# JSONObject contains info, but JSONArray getting "No value for xxxx"

Tags: android, json

Here's the code getting the JSON data:

```
class GetFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL_ITUNES);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                JSONObject responseData = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                Log.e("ItemListActivity", "responseData = " + String.valueOf(responseData));

                JSONArray test = responseData.getJSONArray("entry");
                Log.e("ItemListActivity", "test = " + String.valueOf(test.length()));

            } else {
                Log.e("ItemListActivity", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

the log for "responseData" shows all the data, but the log for "test" is showing:  org.json.JSONException: No value for entry.

**Why is there no value for entry?**

I'm doing this to get better with JSON, using the itunes json page for the data:  http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topgrossingapplications/sf=143441/limit=25/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "entry" array is not a root element. It is contained within the "feed" object.

```
{
    "feed": {
        "author": {
            ...
        },
        "entry": [
            ...
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

You will have to grab the "feed" object first and then pull the "entry" array out of it.

```
JSONObject feedJson = responseData.getJSONObject("feed");
JSONArray test = feedJson.getJSONArray("entry");
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you very much

Comment: It's not letting me yet.  Definitely will though

Comment: Oh, I guess that was pretty quick haha.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
JSONArray test = responseData.getJSONArray("feed");
```